# Change values of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i have this object

```
Object {
  "Info": "/mall/Id",
  "Logo": "/mall/Id/Logo",
  "Photo": "/mall/Id/photo",
}
```

i cant know the keys of the object, so how can i change in the values "/mall/Id" to "/mall/1" whit

`.replace('Id', Id);`

i know i can iterate whit Object.values but when i do that i got the same response

```
  ARRAY.map(El => 
  {
     Object.values(El).map(El => 
     {
        return(
           El = El.replace('Id', this.props.Id)
        )
     })
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object.keys()` to iterate the JSON keys and replace the string.

```js
const input = {
  "Info": "/mall/Id",
  "Logo": "/mall/Id/Logo",
  "Photo": "/mall/Id/photo",
}

Object.keys(input).forEach(key => {
  input[key] = input[key].replace('Id', this.props.Id);
});

console.log(input)
```

Comment: yes but i got and error input[key].replace is not a function

Comment: @LuisDanielMonsalveRuiz you must've getting a value (`input[key]`) which is not a string. This solution works otherwise.

Comment: you are right i pass an array i need to do input[0] before the forEach and it works

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative look-ahead regular expression pattern to match the desired value in the request URL (with a preceding forward-slash).

e.g. `/\/(?!/)Id/`

```js
const requestFromTemplate = (template, key, value) =>
  (exp => Object.entries(template).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({
      ...acc,
      [k]: v.replace(exp, value)
    }), {}))
  (new RegExp(`(?!/)${key}`));

const mallTemplate = {
  "Info": "/mall/Id",
  "Logo": "/mall/Id/Logo",
  "Photo": "/mall/Id/photo",
};

const firstMall = requestFromTemplate(mallTemplate, 'Id', 1);

console.log(firstMall);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Is there any advantages of using a `RegExp` here, then using a loop? Perhaps the non-string cases?

Comment: @SinanYaman It creates a regular expression based on the `key` that you pass-in. It's a generic solution. **Note:** I also included the raw expression as an example.

Comment: Also avoids inadvertent replacement `mall/Id/promotionIdeas`